# Shunning a directory with Fossil

Tags: version-control, fossil

Fossil has a shunning mechanism, which I believe may be used to keep certain files from version control.

I have a directory named `R`, which I wish to control except for a sub-directory inside of it, named `library`, which I wish to exclude. How can I "shun" the sub-directory?

My usual workflow is something like this:

```
fossil new ../fossils/R.fsl
fossil open ../fossils/R.fsl
fossil add .
fossil ci -m "a commit"
fossil close R.fsl
```

The help page is here, but I still couldn't figure it out:

http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/shunning.wiki

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, you're looking for a way to keep specific files **out** of version control.

In that case, you're probably looking for the `ignore-glob` setting.

That setting allows you to specify (chunks of) paths that should be left out of the repository.

For example, if you wanted to leave all files in the subdirectory `skip`, and you also wanted to keep all `*.bak` files everywhere out of your repo, you could achieve this with the following command:

```
fossil set ignore-glob "skip/,*.bak"
```

The `fossil set ignore-glob` takes a comma-separated list, so this means any file starting with `skip/` will be ignored, and all files matching the `*.bak` glob will be ignored as well.

If you want to test your `ignore-glob` setting first (it can be a tad tricky to get right, in my experience), you can test it using the [extras](http://fossil-scm.org/fossil/help/extras) command. `fossil extras` will normally show all files present in the working folder (and its subfolders), but are not in the repository.  You can override the `ignore-glob` setting using the `--override` command-line switch; thereby allowing you to test it. If it works OK, you can save that ignore-glob with the `settings` command, as described above.

***Do NOT use shun for this!***

As the documentation clearly says, shunning is *not recommended*. It should only be used with great care, and only if you understand exactly what it does, because you can seriously fuck up your repository if you use it the wrong way.
Your question makes it clear that you don't understand its use, so I strongly suggest forgetting about shun until you're more familiar with the working of Fossil.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, you're correct. Every 2 years or so I try setting up a version control system and usually give up (I've tried bazaar, git, subversion, and maybe more, but having to look up the manual every time I quickly give up, fossil has been a little kinder to me, but still I haven't committed in about 2 years because of this subdirectory thing). Do you mind giving an example of the ignore-glob setting, to ignore a subdirectory named library inside of directory R? Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickT: good luck!  A tip: subscribe to the [fossil-users](http://lists.fossil-scm.org:8080/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/fossil-users) mailing list; if you run into trouble, they can usually help you out. (The list's archives can be found [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/fossil-users@lists.fossil-scm.org/)).

Answer (score 2):

Do not use shunning. Use this:

```
cd R
fossil settings ignore-glob "library/*"
fossil settings ignore-glob
fossil ls
fossil extra
```

Here is a good guide for start https://www.fossil-scm.org/xfer/doc/tip/www/quickstart.wiki

Answer (score 1):

```
cd your_repo
fossil settings ignore-glob "folder1/,folder2/,*.apk,*.dll,*.o,*.class"
```

here replace your folder names to ignore for example bin/ build/ etc and add filename extensions with comma separations.

```
fossil settings ignore-glob
```

type above code in terminal in order to see what all file types and folders are ignored by fossil.   Please note that the fossil ignore-glob needs to be done in each clone of the repository .

or   another way is to run `fossil server` or `fossil ui`  then open localhost:8080

go to [admin page > settings page](http://localhost:8080/setup_settings) you can find status of ignored files
for here you can edit them also
example

[image: ignored file types in settings page]